# Can jboss console log size affect the site performance

Tags: java, logging, jboss, io, wildfly-8

Our enterprise application deployed in Jboss wildfly 8.2. The jboss console log is being set during the startup using an environment variable - JBOSS_CONSOLE. This ensures that any thread dump triggered using kill -QUIT  is dumped to jboss_console.log. The GC statistics(collected using -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails) are also sent to this file.

The rotation of the log file is done by

cat /dev/null > jboss_console.log

Even though this brings down the file size, on triggering a thread dump using, the file size increases to (size of file before rotation + size of new thread dump). So, the file size doesn't come down unless we restart the jboss and explicitly remove the file.

Also, there is a clear discrepancy in output of du & ls commands.

[root@myserver logs]# du -csh jboss_console.log

**28M**     jboss_console.log

**28M**     total

[root@myserver logs]# ls -lrtS jboss_console.log -h

-rwxr-xr-x. 1 admin admin **1.7G** Jun 22 05:28 jboss_console.log

The issue is that after a month of jboss restart, the file system operations slow down to one tenth. I.e. if I had a simple static text file of size 1 GB hosted in my apache, downloading it to my local box would be done in like say 3 mins. But after a month, the same operation takes 30 mins. On restarting the jboss, the issue clears off immediately. There is no significant cpu, memory or IO spike in the system.

Is this being caused by the jboss_console.log size?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here the `jboss_console.log` is created by piping the `stdout` and `stderr` streams of the process. If that's the case then the issue likely at the OS level.

By default the `CONSOLE` handler will just log to `System.out`. If the size of the log is a concern you could just remove or disable the `CONSOLE` handler since the `server.log` will contain the same information.

To remove the `CONSOLE` handler from the root logger you can use the following CLI command.

```
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:remove-handler(name=CONSOLE)
```

I'm not sure this is really answer to your question, but it's one option to keep the size of the `jboss_console.log` down a bit.